# How to make loop movement of a servo?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, pi-2, rpi.gpio

how to make a loop movement of 6 servos controlled by pots, while pressing the button saves the movement once pulled out the loop start.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# servo_pot.py
# 2016-07-25
# Public Domain

import time

import pigpio  # http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

SERVO=14

MIN_SERVO=500
MAX_SERVO=2500

MIN_POT_CAP=0
MAX_POT_CAP=1023

def map(val, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
  return (val - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to Pi.

if not pi.connected:
  exit()

adc = pi.spi_open(1, 40000, 0) # Open SPI channel 1.

 while True:

   try:

     c, d = pi.spi_xfer(adc, [1, 0x80, 0]) # Read channel 0.

     v = ((d[1]<<8) | d[2]) & 0x3FF

     micros = map(v, MIN_POT_CAP, MAX_POT_CAP, MIN_SERVO, MAX_SERVO)

     pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(SERVO, micros)

     time.sleep(0.02)

  except:

     break

print("\nexiting...")

pi.spi_close(adc) # Release SPI handle.

pi.stop() # Disconnect from Pi.
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "while pressing the button saves the movement once pulled out the loop start"?

Comment: while pressing the button and moving the pots it saves the movement and once lift your hand it starts applying the saved movement
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLnAJ-mSElE

Comment: It sounds like you want the ability to record then playback servo motion.  That really wasn't what I understood from your question.  Perhaps search for diorama software which may be the right sort of area.

Comment: Adafruit have a [good writeup](https://learn.adafruit.com/trainable-robotic-arm/final-steps-and-video?view=all#sketch) of a similar system built around an Arduino. A quick skim over the code suggests it's not too complex and might be suitable for porting (they write values to EEPROM, you should be able to write them to disk). If you're going to have problems with anything I suspect it might be proper clocking during recording and playback. Arduinos are great for regular timing, Pis less so.

Comment: While not really much to do with Pi's you did get the opportunity to get an epic answer. I hope this answer will live on to help others searching for similar problems. Can we protect this question?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, the perfect excuse to dabble in some source/values stuff in GPIO Zero! As others have commented, doing this on a Pi won't give you precise timing but this *might* be good enough (and the code's quite simple).

## Component "values"

One of the concepts we've tried to introduce in GPIO Zero is that all components have a `value` which for single components is represented as a single number. For simple things like an LED that'll be 0 (off) and 1 (on). Same thing for a button. For more complex things like a Servo that might would be a floating point value from -1 (all the way counter-clockwise) to 0 (mid-position) to 1 (all the clockwise). Naturally, a pot (via some ADC like an MCP3008) would be a float from 0 to 1.

So, all components have a `value` property which we can read to obtain this number. They also have a `values` property which provides an infinite iterator of these numbers (every time you request another value from it, it reads the `value` property). This is useful in combination with the `source` property. This exists on components which can be manipulated from the Pi (as opposed to externally), so LEDs have a `source` property, servos have a `source` property, but buttons don't (because the Pi can't manipulate the state of the button, only something external can). When the `source` property is assigned an iterator of values it continually reads that iterator (with a defined delay between each read) and assigns the value read to the component.

### LEDs and Buttons

Hence we can make an [LED](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_output.html#led) flash in response to a [Button](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_input.html#button) simply by doing:

```
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

led = LED(20) # all pin numbers are BCM GPIO numbers
btn = Button(21)
led.source = btn.values
pause() # let the script run until Ctrl+C
```

### Servos and pots

Likewise we can make a [Servo](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_output.html#servo) follow a pot (linked to an [MCP3008](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_spi.html#gpiozero.MCP3008)) like so:

```
from gpiozero import Servo, MCP3008
from signal import pause

pot = MCP3008(channel=0)
servo = Servo(20)
servo.source = pot.values
pause() # let the script run until Ctrl+C
```

The script above assumes the MCP3008 is wired to the usual SPI pins with CS0. Hardware SPI will be used if SPI is enabled (see `raspi-config`). If it isn't, you'll get a warning message and GPIO Zero will fallback to a bit-banging implementation on the same pins. Additional keyword args can be specified to select other pins if you require; the `channel` keyword simply specifies which ADC channel to read values from.

The script also uses the defaults for the servo timings. GPIO Zero's defaults are designed to be conservatively safe because pushing some servos too far can break them. The three parameters that control the limits in the `Servo` constructor are:

- `frame_width` - the time between pulses. This defaults to 20ms which is correct for the vast majority of servos. You'll never need to alter this unless you're dealing with some expensive / esoteric servos.
- `min_pulse_width` - the pulse time associated with the minimum angle of the servo. This defaults to 1ms which is correct for *many* but certainly not all servos. Some go down to 0.5ms.
- `max_pulse_width` - the pulse time associated with the maximum angle of the servo. This defaults to 2ms which again is correct for many but not all servos. Some go up to 2.5ms.

If your servo doesn't appear to be turning all the way, try the following script and alter these parameters by a *small* amount (0.1ms for example, so change 1/1000 to 0.9/1000 and 2/1000 to 2.1/1000) each time until you reach the desired range or your servo sounds like its complaining:

```
from __future__ import division # in case you're on Python 2
from gpiozero import Servo
from time import sleep
servo = Servo(20, min_pulse_width=1/1000, max_pulse_width=2/1000)
while True:
    servo.min()
    sleep(1)
    servo.mid()
    sleep(1)
    servo.max()
    sleep(1)
```

If you're feeling brave you can try jumping straight to the following settings which are the other "common" limits (just beware you *can* break servos by pushing beyond their limits and that unfortunately many manufacturers are poor at documenting the actual limits of their devices):

```
servo = Servo(20, min_pulse_width=0.5/1000, max_pulse_width=2.5/1000)
```

### Filtering values

The servo has a range from -1 to 1, whilst the pot ranges from 0 to 1 so we probably want to [scale](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_tools.html#gpiozero.tools.scaled) the values:

```
from gpiozero import Servo, MCP3008
from gpiozero.tools import scaled
from signal import pause

pot = MCP3008(channel=0)
servo = Servo(20)
servo.source = scaled(pot.values, -1, 1)
pause() # let the script run until Ctrl+C
```

### Recording values

What about recording those values? Easy: just make an iterator function which appends each value to a list and then yields that value so the pot can respond to it:

```
from gpiozero import Servo, MCP3008
from gpiozero.tools import scaled
from time import sleep

pot = MCP3008(channel=0)
servo = Servo(20)
recording = []

def record(values):
    for value in values:
        recording.append(value)
        yield value

servo.source_delay = 1/100
servo.source = record(scaled(pot.values, -1, 1))
print('Recording for 10 seconds')
sleep(10)
print('Playing back %d values' % len(recording))
servo.source = recording
sleep(10)
```

## Putting it all together

Now, let's put it all together with a button to trigger the recording / playback (we'll use GPIO Zero's event handling for that; note that there's also [when_held](http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_held) which might be useful for something):

```
from __future__ import division # in case you're on Python 2

from gpiozero import MCP3008, Servo, Button
from gpiozero.tools import scaled
from itertools import cycle
from signal import pause


class ServoRecorder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.recording = None
        self.record_button = Button(21)
        self.record_button.when_pressed = self.start_recording
        self.record_button.when_released = self.stop_recording
        self.servo = Servo(20)
        self.servo.source_delay = 1/100 # read up to 100 values/s
        self.pot = MCP3008(channel=0)

    def record(self, values):
        self.recording = []
        for value in values:
            self.recording.append(value)
            yield value

    def start_recording(self):
        print('Recording')
        self.servo.source = self.record(scaled(self.pot.values, -1, 1))

    def stop_recording(self):
        print('Playing back %d values' % len(self.recording))
        self.servo.source = cycle(self.recording)


recorder = ServoRecorder()
pause()
```

You could easily extend this with another button to save and load recordings (the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) modules in the standard library should be fine for that).

### A note on PWM implementations

One final thing I should note: the standard pin driver that GPIO Zero uses is `RPi.GPIO`. This uses software PWM which means servos will jitter a bit. If you want much smoother servo control I'd recommend using the pigpio backend instead. This is pretty simple as of the latest version of Raspbian and GPIO Zero. Firstly, make sure the pigpio daemon is started, then tell GPIO Zero to use the PiGPIOPin factory (case sensitive, sorry! This'll probably change to just "pigpio", case insensitive, in the next version for simplicity) before starting your script:

```
$ sudo systemctl start pigpiod
$ export GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=PiGPIOPin
$ python3 servo_record.py
```

I don't know quite how many servos you can drive with these backends - I've tried the above script with one and it seems to work nicely, but I don't have 6 spare servos (or pots) to try with!

Comment: Epic answer.. stack exchange really needs and Epic answer thingy

Comment: Thank for your great answer, i really appreciate your effort :D
but when i have connected everything the pot doesn't make the servo moves to it's end, there is always many space that the servo can move.

Comment: Ah, hang on a sec, I'll add a bit ...

Comment: There we go - added some bits about finding servo limits